# Controller advice not handle my exception in Spring Boot 1.5.3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have rest api application in Spring Boot 1.5.3, I'm using security to login and authenticate every request by token to my api. I want add my custom exception with unauthorized exception when user not found by token. Class with exception is added but every response has 500 code but I want 401 response code. Belowe is my code.

StatelessAuthenticationFilter

```
           public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

            private final TokenAuthenticationService              tokenAuthenticationService;

            public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService taService) {
            this.tokenAuthenticationService = taService;
            }

            @Override
            public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) req));
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            }
```

StatelessLoginFilter

```
           public class StatelessLoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

            private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;
            private final UserServiceImpl userService;

            public StatelessLoginFilter(String urlMapping, TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService,
                           UserServiceImpl userDetailsService, AuthenticationManager authManager) {
            super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(urlMapping));
            this.userService = userDetailsService;
            this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
            setAuthenticationManager(authManager);
            }

            @Override
            public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {

            String headerCredentials = request.getHeader("BasicAuth");

            if (headerCredentials == null) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("No header in request");
            }

            String credentials = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(headerCredentials), "UTF-8");
            if (!credentials.contains((":"))) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Wrong header");
            }
            String [] credentialsArray = credentials.split(":");

            String login = credentialsArray[0];
            String password = credentialsArray[1];

            final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken loginToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(login, password);
            return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(loginToken);
            }

            @Override
            protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {

            // Lookup the complete User2 object from the database and create an Authentication for it
            final User authenticatedUser = userService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
            final UserAuthentication userAuthentication = new UserAuthentication(authenticatedUser);

            // Add the custom token as HTTP header to the response
            tokenAuthenticationService.addAuthentication(response, userAuthentication);

            // Add the authentication to the Security context
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(userAuthentication);
            }
```

MyOwnException

```
            public class MyOwnException extends RuntimeException {

            public MyOwnException(String message) {
            super(message);

            }
```

RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler

```
         @ControllerAdvice
        public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler  extends DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver {

            @ExceptionHandler(MyOwnException.class)
            void handleMyOwnException(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            }
        }
```

StatelessAuthenticationSecurityConfig

```
        @EnableWebSecurity
        @Configuration
        @Order(1)
        public class StatelessAuthenticationSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
            private UserServiceImpl userService;

            @Autowired
            private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

            public StatelessAuthenticationSecurityConfig() {
            super(true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("USER")
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN").and()

                // custom JSON based authentication by POST of {"username":"<name>","password":"<password>"} which sets the token header upon authentication
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessLoginFilter("/login", tokenAuthenticationService, userService, authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

                // custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the client
                .addFilterBefore(new StatelessAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
            }

            @Bean
            @Override
            public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
            }

            @Override
            protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
            }

            @Bean
            CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
            CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
            configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
            configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
            configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
            configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
            UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
            source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
            return source;
            }

            @Override
            protected UserServiceImpl userDetailsService() {
            return userService;
            }
```

VoteApp

```
        @SpringBootApplication
        public class VoteApp {
            public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(VoteApp.class, args);
            }

            @Bean
            public Filter characterEncodingFilter() {
            CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
            characterEncodingFilter.setForceEncoding(true);
            return characterEncodingFilter;
            }
        }
```

UserServiceImpl

```
@Service
```

public class UserServiceImpl implements org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService {

```
@Autowired
private UserRepository userRepository;

@Override
public final User loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    final User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("user not found");
    }
    return user;
}

public User findByToken(String token) throws MyOwnException {
    final User user = userRepository.findByToken(token);
    if (user == null) {
        throw new MyOwnException("user by token not found");
    }
    return user;
}

public void save(User user) {
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you share the code where your exception being thrown?

Comment: I attached above.

Comment: I think problem is spring security, but I don't know how resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously `@ControllerAdvice` can't handle your exception because controller methods has not been called yet. I mean you exception being thrown in servlet filter. I think you going to have to catch it manually, smth like this:

```
public class StatelessAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public StatelessAuthenticationFilter(TokenAuthenticationService taService) {
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = taService;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication auth = null;
        try {
           auth = tokenAuthenticationService.getAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) req);
        } catch (MyOwnException e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add @ResponseStatus annotation to your exception handler of controller advice.

For more information visit -   [Exception Handling in Spring MVC](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc)

Comment: I'e added @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CONFLICT) but doesn't work.